# How to install "last" in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

When I tried to run `last` to get recently login users, I got an error:

```
-bash: last: command not found
```

So how can I install it? I'm using centos 7.0. Sorry if this is a simple question, but I cannot find any answer online regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask `yum` to search for the package that provides a specific file in the filesystem, and you can use globs to widen the search. For example:

```
yum whatprovides */last
```

This will tell you that the package `sysvinit-tools` provides `/usr/bin/last`.

I was a little surprised to see that you didn't have `last` installed, as that's a pretty basic program that ought to always be installed. But, you learn something new every day... In a future version of RHEL/CentOS, `last` will be provided in the `util-linux` package, and should always be installed even on the most minimal system.

Comment: It's a good idea to quote `*/last` just in case it matches a pathname starting in your pwd.